# ThreadAbortException, Classic ASP and ASP.NET MVC apps

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, asp-classic, threadabortexception

I am also getting that "Thread was being aborted" error message.

I know that this is an old issue but I don't think it's a redirect thing (at least no inside .NET because I don't have Response.Redirects there - only RedirectResults that would call Response.Redirect(url, false) internally)* and I don't think it's a recycling issue due to inactivity either.

It's happening in different scenarios but one that called my attention was: I have a window.open(url) being called inside a classic asp page. This url maps to a ASP.NET MVC controller action**. SOMETIMES when this window.open occurs I am getting a ThreadAbortException.

Could someone help me?

```
* http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/EN-US/#top
** I have two apps in the same server: Classic ASP and ASP.NET MVC
```

Comment: The stack trace of the exception should point you to the origin.

Comment: That's where the problem is. The stacks are completely different from one exception to the other. We are thinking that it might be related to our deployment policies once we sent the app to the test server many times a day.

Comment: Just confirming... it was a deployment problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just confirming... it was a deployment problem.